# Problem using a Pipe in Angular to filter some data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown box where I added a search box to it and I want to filter the Options based on the textbox entry. In my case i also say if searchText is null or empty return all data which works fine. But if I submit a filter I get this error.

> core.js:6142 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'toLowerCase')
> at option-filter.pipe.ts:13:47
> at Array.filter ()
> at OptionFilterPipe.transform (option-filter.pipe.ts:13:16)

Here is my template code

```
 <igx-drop-down-item *ngFor="let option of options |  optionFilter : optionsearch.value : 'name'" [value]="option">
    {{ option.name }}
    </igx-drop-down-item>
```

And this is my pipe code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'optionFilter' })
export class OptionFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 
  public transform(data: any[], searchText: any, fieldName: string): any {
  if (searchText == null || data == null || searchText == '' ) {
    return data;
  }
  console.log(data)
  console.log('Serch Text : ' + searchText)
  console.log('FieldName : ' + fieldName)
   return data.filter(item => item[fieldName].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase') at option-filter.pipe.ts:13:47 " clear enough ? item[fieldName] doesn't exist it says

Comment: That what i thought too. I included a screenshot of data and it includes name. I get the same error when hardcoding item.name

Comment: can you replicate the issue in stackblitz or somewhere?? then it will be just few mins of work for us to solve.. but right now without debugging code, its taking lot of time thinking what could be the error..

Comment: I have to see if it's possible to create one as its part of a more complex implementation and data comes from Remote API

Comment: Change `item[fieldname]` to `item.fieldname`?

Comment: problem what i see here is, typescript doesn't know you are passing the Object key. for objects item[fieldname] isn't a preffered way. You need to do item.name. Then when you want dynamically just declare your key as key of your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in my case it had to do with when it was called and there was no data since it was a async call. Fieldname was not an issue and i could not elimnate as it is required to tell the function on which field to filter in the object.

Below is code that fixed the issue

```
return data.filter(item => item[fieldName]?.toString()?.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText?.toString()?.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
// import { ServerDropdownOption } from 'somewhere';


type DynamicKey = keyof typeof ServerDropdownOption;

@Pipe({ name: 'optionFilter' })
export class OptionFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 
  public transform( data: ServerDropdownOption[], searchText: string, fieldName: string ): ServerDropdownOption[] {
  if (searchText == null || data == null || searchText == '' ) {
    return data;
  }
  const fieldRef = fieldName as DynamicKey;
  return data.filter(item => item[fieldRef].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
}
```

Should do, Haven't tested

PS: import that ServerDropdownOption from appropriate place